# Ansible playbook to ensure Ruby gems are installed

Tags: ansible, windows

Can I use ansible to make sure certain Ruby gems are installed on a list of Windows 7 hosts? How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. Use the [gem module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/gem_module.html#gem-module).